# accessing mongodb document field names and its values through iteration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have a mongodb document in the **products** collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51b1eac0311b6dd93a000001"),
    "name" : "Apple",
    "price" : "34.45"
}
```

products_controller.rb for **def show** part:

```
def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

I imagine the code would seem like below in the **show.html.erb**:

```
<% @product.each do |f|%>
     <p>f.label</p> # this is only an image code
     <p>f.value</p> # this is only an image code
<% end %>
```

How the code at the lines 2 and 3 on Rails 3 should look like in a generic way so it would show like? :

```
name: Apple
price: 34.45
```

Number of fields can be 20, so I don't want to write the same code for 20 fields.

I'm using Rails 3 with Mongoid. I think it's not a mongodb-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item  in YourcollectionName)
{
    var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid models have an `attributes` method that returns a hash of the attributes. If you iterate over that hash you'll be yielded the name and value of each entry.

For example

```
<% @product.attributes.each do |name, value| %>
  <p>
    <%= name%> : <%= value %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

You'd need some more sophisticated formatting code for pretty output for all the kinds of values you might get (dates, arrays, hashes etc.)

Comment: Can you give some specific example?